# Which timezone do we live in on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, timezone

Is my local time considered in the daily reputation points cap, or number of votes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Kop has said, the rep cap (etc) is based on [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). However, your comments suggest you think you're in CET - but no countries are currently observing CET. Central Europe is generally observing [CEST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cest.html), which is UTC+2.

You haven't specified your location, but assuming you live somewhere which is CET in winter, and you've recently gone onto summer time by advancing your clock by 1 hour, you're now in UTC+2. That means the "rep day" starts at your local 2am.

Comment: Oh dear - somebody asked a "timezone" question with Jon in the room. This could take a while... ;-p (said in jest, people)

Answer (score 6):

We live in UTC land.

Comment: What is UTC compared to CET ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_%28disambiguation%29

Comment: I know the first word in the acronym is Unicorn, but I can't get the rest :P

Comment: @Stacker - CET is UTC+1 http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cet.html

Comment: Unicorn Coordinated Time. Even unicorns need a bit of coordination from time to time.