# How do I fix the time under the reputation tab?

Tags: support, timezone

The reputation tab is not adjusting to my current time zone, so questions I've asked a few hours ago is being displayed as yesterday... It's not yesterday! Is there an option somewhere for me to quickly change this?

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow displays all time in the same time zone--based on [UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/in-which-timezone-do-we-live-in-so). You can't change the personal time zone you're in; instead, everyone operates from within the same time zone.

Comment: Here's the relevant FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start