# Clock on Stack Exchange

Tags: support

Where do I set the Stack Exchange clock for my time zone? I live in the [Eastern Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (ET), Daylight Savings or Summer Time. At 11:00 each night (UTC 3:00, according to the notice at the top), the records for my reputation points switch over to a new day, as though my clock is set for a time zone further east. Is there a way for me to change this in my account settings? I think my time zone is UTC -5 by some standards. I am unable to find my primary account with settings, name, email, etc. I never log out. I guess I'm lost.

Comment: Unfortunately, the system uses UTC time for everyone, and there's no way for users to change it: [In which Timezone do we live in SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/in-which-timezone-do-we-live-in-so)

Comment: Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) [is UTC−04:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone#Daylight_saving_time).